# AIML - Include library to AIML Project

Tags: xml, bots, chatbot, aiml

I'm working on a ChatBot using PandoraBots. We want to include a counter system that calculates a score for the user. For that we need basic equations and comparison.

I found the AIML Standard Library (https://www.pandorabots.com/docs/aiml-libraries/#aiml-standard-library) and tried to include it to the bot (https://github.com/pandorabots/aiml-utilities/blob/master/lib/aimlstandardlibrary.aiml) but failed to include it to the bot/use it.

How can I use the library / include it to the bot and
Is there an other way to save variables and work with them in AIML?

Answer (score 1):

Download the AIML file and upload it to your bot - republish and you are ready to go. Instructions on how to use the different functions are here: https://www.pandorabots.com/docs/aiml-libraries/
I also did a tutorial video on using maths in AIML here: https://youtu.be/fSu3kSb2z_M